# How to keep graham cracker crust from falling apart

Tags: baking, dessert

Whenever I make any type of square using a graham cracker crust, it always falls apart upon slicing.  No matter what I try, either following the receipe exactly,increasing or decreasing the amount of butter, slicing it when it is cold and hot, it always crumbles. There must be a way to succeed or they wouldn't call them squares. Anybody know the secret?

Comment: I've always had it crumble a little bit.  If it's entirely falling apart, are you packing it down well, before filling?  I use a small metal ramakin to really tamp it down.  (the ramakin makes it easier to press it into the sides, and even into the corner)

Comment: Do you pre-bake the crust before adding the filling?

Comment: Could you please post an example of the ratios in the crust recipe you are using, so we can better help?

Answer (score 2):

It's unrealistic to expect a graham cracker crust to slice perfectly. However, it shouldn't fall apart completely. The problem could be in the ingredient amounts, the baking time, or in not pressing it effectively. Check this out

http://www.makeitlikeaman.com/2014/01/11/graham-cracker-crust/

and see if it helps. It has a good method for pressing.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same crumbly problem when I haven't blind baked it long enough ( look for the slightly darker color and note strong aroma of deliciousness before removing from the oven ).  Also check the knife you are using.  A serrated bread knife can be very helpful in a cleaner cut through a graham cracker crust.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Three thoughts...

- Increase the sugar a little. It helps to bind and keep crumbles at bay.
- I don't know if this applies, but, if the dessert is chilled, leave it out for 5-10 minutes before cutting. The butter in the crust will soften a bit and not be as prone to cracking.
- Make sure to bake the crust to slightly brown before filling.

Hope those help. I just made a deep dish key lime pie without crust cracking. Those are the things I did (because I've also had that trouble before). [Here are some pics](http://www.luckynumber3.com/2016/02/stabilized-whipped-cream.html?m=1) of the pie on my blog.

Comment: @lucky- this shouldn't be "community wiki". We don't really use that anymore and you don't get the rep when it's upvoted.

Comment: @Sobachatina Hi...yes, someone else taught me that yesterday. I don't see how to edit it off. I definitely won't do that in the future. Sorry for any confusion I've caused. Thank you for telling me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Does the recipe call for sugar and pre-baking for the crust, besides the butter? 
 I make cheesecake and the recipes all have a sugar, butter and graham cracker for the crust. The crust is required to be pre-baked, and cooled before filling. I have been lucky with my crusts, unless too thick on the side of a spring pan, they all come out clean.